# BAD ACCESS error using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.goToKeyIdea))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
gesture.view?.tag = num // This line may be unnecessary
kView.tag = num
kView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
kView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)




@objc func goToKeyIdea (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) async {
    let canAccess = await MUser.sharedInstance.canAccessTextSummaries(book: self.data)
    
    if (!canAccess) {
        self.pay();
    } else {
        let params = [
            "bookId": self.book.subid,
            "UserId": String(MUser.sharedInstance.userId)
        ];
        Flurry.log(eventName: "BookSummaryRead", parameters: params);
        
        await MUser.sharedInstance.incrementRead()
        await MUser.sharedInstance.handleBookStarted(book: self.book)
        
        self.selectedKeyIdea = sender.view?.tag ?? 0
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toText", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

When someone taps on the view referenced above, the app crashes with error BAD ACCESS. I put a breakpoint. It never reaches the code goToKeyIdea. Does anyone see issues with the code above? Maybe something changed in the recent version of ios?

Comment: Please show the action method. By the way `self.` is not needed

Comment: done @vadian but it doesn't access the action method

Comment: An action method  exposed to Objective-C cannot be `async`. Wrap the `await`ing methods in a `Task`.

Comment: The Task worked. It works now! thanks guys

Comment: @vadian you should post your comment about not using async methods as `@objc` targets as an answer so the OP can accept it. (well seen as usual.) I was getting ready to post the same thing when I saw that you had already provided that info in your comment.

Comment: BTW, when you get a crash, it helps to include a copy of the full error message and the stack trace in your question (including a screens-shot of the debugger showing the call stack.) In this particular case we were able to diagnose your problem from the code you posted, but that isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` is Swift-only. It cannot be exposed to `@objc`.

Just remove `async` and put the code related to `async/await` in a `Task`.

```
@objc func goToKeyIdea(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    Task {
        let canAccess = await MUser.sharedInstance.canAccessTextSummaries(book: self.data)
        
        if !canAccess { // no parentheses in Swift
            self.pay() // no semicolons in Swift
        } else {
            let params = [
                "bookId": self.book.subid,
                "UserId": String(MUser.sharedInstance.userId)
            ] 
            Flurry.log(eventName: "BookSummaryRead", parameters: params)
            
            await MUser.sharedInstance.incrementRead()
            await MUser.sharedInstance.handleBookStarted(book: self.book)
            
            self.selectedKeyIdea = sender.view?.tag ?? 0
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toText", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```